# How to raise ADF EO Validation Error from Groovy

Tags: oracle-adf

I have an Entity validation of type script expression defined. Based on *which* validation logic (described in groovy) fails, I need to throw the respective error.

The groovy logic is as follows,

```
if( attr1.compareTo('a')){
    adf.error.raise(argument1);
    return false;
}
if( attr1.compareTo('b')){
    adf.error.raise(argument2);
    return false;
}
return true;
```

I have Added the messages under Failure Handling Tab as shown below

**Screenshot**
[image: Click to see screenshot]

**Now the problem is, I dont know what the argument should be?**

I couldn't find any documentation online about this.

When Message Id (check screenshot) is provided as input, following error is obtained,

STRINGMANAGER: Key:  not found in bundle oracle.javatools.resourcebundle.ResourceBundleRT

Comment: By default it's checking in the bundle 'oracle.javatools.resourcebundle.ResourceBundleRT' instead of the fnd messages resource bundle. How do I change this?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to check what bundle is being used under Project Properties > Resource Bundles. Maybe this will help: http://hasamali.blogspot.com/2012/09/oracle-adf-model-and-view-controller.html